# How capture Etw in kernelmode?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, etw

I'm trying to capture some syscalls using Etw in my driver, to be more precise I need capture NtWriteVirtualMemory and NtReadVirtualMemory usermode calls, i tried using the provider: [Microsoft Windows Threat Intelligence](https://github.com/repnz/etw-providers-docs/blob/c3068742397bbeb69c49f8a942b4c2724e219755/Manifests-Win10-17134/Microsoft-Windows-Threat-Intelligence.xml), I used PerfView to dump the Threat Inteligence xml for Windows 10 1909 [and used message compiler to compile the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-event-tracing-to-kernel-mode-drivers#3-compile-the-instrumentation-manifest-by-using-the-message-compiler-mcexe)(exactly what microsoft said to do) and checked [Microsoft Etw sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/tracing/evntdrv), but for some reason my callback is called only once(when EtwRegister is called in my DriverEntry), to register my callback 
i just called EtwRegister, what i should do for my callback be called? I'm using Microsoft sample code with a header file that was generated by mc.exe(message compiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you looked at is for an ETW Provider, not a consumer.
I'm not sure there is a documented way to consume ETW events from kernel. You can check samples for consuming events from user mode:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/tracing/SystemTraceControl

Also note that Microsoft Windows Threat Intelligence ETW provider can only be consumed in Anti-Malware PPL type process. It requires having an Early Launch AntiMalware driver with a matching AntiMalware service. More info can be found at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/early-launch-antimalware
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-

Comment: I didn't know that to capture Microsoft Windows Threat Intelligente ETW needs to be an Anti Malware PPL process, thank you for the information.